# How to copy only modified & new files from one folder to new location?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to copy only modified & new files from one folder to new location?
the destination folder should be created by current date and time. While copying files, the folder structure should be created automatically.

I know there are many similar questions already answered, but here I want to copy only modified and new files to a folder.
I tried below given solution, but it's not working:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "current_date=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

robocopy "D:\source" "d:\%current_date%" /MIR > d:\backup.log
```

Comment: Have a look at `forfiles`, it will make your life easier :)

Comment: How *exactly* is your code "not working"? What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: The problem here is: how do you determine what is a modified or new file?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Here is my improved question,

We have SVN repository configured(check-out) on our local machine. We take SVN update and export changes to a folder.
later We have to deploy those changes on web server manually, but before that We have to take backup of those files which will be replaced.

To do this I want to write a batch file, which will read changes from the exported folder and take backup of the same files from Web Server.
Is it possible?

Comment: sounds like a job for the archive attribute: `The Archive attribute (A) is used to mark files that have changed since they were previously backed up. The (A) flag is automatically updated by Windows as the file is saved.` [source](https://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html)

Comment: If you need to provide additional information please [edit] your question. Do not bury it in comments.

Comment: When you say `export changes to a folder`, do you mean you have a folder with only the changed files?